# How to pass the 2D array point to the other functions?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, point

I have a question. I wanna pass my own 2D array to `pass` function.And in that function,i will change my own array.So,there is a `return`.What i exactly know is that the code blow can be accepted by the compiler.But, i don't why it is.When i take the `int (* aaa)[3];` out of the `main` function,it works well.But , when it is inside the `main`,there will throw an exception that `unable to use the uninitialized aaa`.I wonder why could this happan.

```
int* pass(int (*a)[3]) {
    a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*2);
    a[0][1] = 1;
    a[0][2] = 2;
    return a;
}
int (* aaa)[3];
int main() {
    aaa = pass(aaa);
    printf("%d", aaa[0][2]);
}
```

this could work.

```
int* pass(int (*a)[3]) {
    a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*2);
    a[0][1] = 1;
    a[0][2] = 2;
    return a;

}

int main() {
    int (* aaa)[3];
    aaa = pass(aaa);
    printf("%d", aaa[0][2]);
}
```

but,this can't work.

Comment: get rid of `(`,`)` around your variable names and the pointer indicator `*`. While `(datatype*) variablename` is fine.. but still a bit parenthesis overdoo.

Comment: @OlSen They are not unnecessary. They change the meaning of the declaration.

Comment: indeed.. is'nt it than a function declaration with anonymous name or soo?

Comment: @OlSen Nope. OP is declaring a pointer to array of three ints. Without parenthesis it would be an array of three pointer to int.

Comment: Of course it can't work. `a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*2);` allocates storage for TWO POINTERS. `a[0][1] = 1;` makes no sense. `int (* aaa)[3];` is a *pointer to array* `int[3]`, You do not have an `int[3]` array anywhere to be found.

Comment: i think here `a` represent  a 2D-array with the parameter `int (*a)[3]` translated in.And ,when i have this formal 2D-array ,i can use it to denote any element-wise of the 2D-array.Right?So,there should be and indeed there is an int[3] 2D-array.

Answer (score 1):

When `int (* aaa)[3];` appears outside of any function, it `aaa` is automatically initialized to a null pointer. When it appears inside a function, it is not initialized.

The code `aaa = pass(aaa);` passes `aaa` to the routine named `pass`. This is a use of the value of `aaa`. When `aaa` has been initialized, that is fine. But, when `aaa` is not initialized and you attempt to pass its value, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. This is what the compiler is warning you about.

Next, let’s examine this code:

```
int* pass(int (*a)[3]) {
    a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*2);
    a[0][1] = 1;
    a[0][2] = 2;
    return a;
}
```

This code never uses the value of `a` that is passed to it. When a function is called, its parameter, `a` in this case, is given a value (which comes from the argument the caller passed). This parameter is a separate variable from the argument. Assigning `a` a value with `a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*2);` does not change the value of `aaa` in the calling routine. So this code assigns a new value to `a` without using the old value.

Because of that, the routine does not need a parameter passed to it. It could be written to use a local variable instead, like this:

```
int (*pass(void))[3] {
    int (*a)[3] = malloc(2 * sizeof *a);
    a[0][1] = 1;
    a[0][2] = 2;
    return a;
}
```

The `void` in this means `pass` does not take any arguments.

Note that I changed `malloc(sizeof(int*)*2` to `malloc(2 * sizeof *a)`. `sizeof(int*)*2` is wrong because it requests space for two pointers to `int`. But `a` points to arrays of three `int`, so, to get two of those, you need space for two arrays of three `int`. That is `2 * sizeof(int [3])`. However, it is easier to write this as `malloc(2 * sizeof *a)`, which means “two of whatever `a` points to”. This is also better because it reduces the frequency with which errors are made: Even if the declaration of `a` is changed, this `sizeof *a` will automatically adjust without needing to be edited. With `sizeof(int [3])`, any edit to the declaration of `a` would require another edit to the `sizeof`.

Also, I removed the `(int*)` to cast the result of `malloc`. In C, a `void *`, which is the type `malloc` returns, will automatically be converted to whatever object pointer type it is assigned to. There is no need for an explicit cast, and using an explicit cast can mask certain errors. (However, if you compile the program with a C++ compiler, it will complain about the lack of a cast, because the rules are different in C++.)

Since the function is returning a pointer to an array of three `int`, not an pointer to an `int`, I changed its declaration to `int (*pass(void))[3]`.

With these changes, the program could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int (*pass(void))[3]
{
    int (*a)[3] = malloc(2 * sizeof *a);
    a[0][1] = 1;
    a[0][2] = 2;
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*aaa)[3] = pass();
    printf("%d\n", aaa[0][2]);
}
```

Comment: `
int* pass(int (*a)[3]) {
    a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*2);
    a[0][1] = 1;
    a[0][2] = 2;
    return a;
}
`
In this,although `aaa` is not used,the` return a` will return a already assigned address to `aaa` .So,aaa can read `aaa[0][2]`,right?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps you a bit to see that C is 'flexible' when it comes to arrays.
Because in the first part the assumed array declaration is given by datalen in malloc of the initAAA function and returns the pointer to the memory that is allocated. And still in the for loop we can access the data with index.

The second part of main declares just *same* data 'bbb' as the first 'aaa' but this time not as pointer and the initiation of the data fields with zeros (0) is done with the curly parenthesis. `{}`. A boring for loop thru all the indexes and set each data field with int 0 would just do it also. But who wants more code than needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int *initAAA(int *p, uint entrys) {
    size_t datalen = entrys * sizeof *p;
    p = malloc(datalen); // p is a pointer here.
    // copy character '0' starting at address of p up to datalen addresses
    // easier then writing a for loop to initiate safely.
    memset(p, 0, datalen);  // defined in string.h
    return p;
}

int main(void) {
    const uint maxAssets = 3;
    const uint entrysPerAsset = 2;
    int *aaa = NULL; // always a good idea, to set pointers to NULL before allocating memory for it. Because you can check if (aaa==NULL) initAAA(...
    uint entrys = maxAssets * entrysPerAsset;
    aaa = initAAA(aaa,entrys);
    printf("address:%p items:%d \n",aaa, entrys);
    for (uint i = 0; i < entrys; i++) {
        printf("%d ", aaa[i]);
    }
    free(aaa); // malloc without free, bad idea!

    printf("\n---\n");
    
    int bbb[maxAssets][entrysPerAsset] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (uint a = 0; a < maxAssets; a++) {
        for (uint e = 0; e < entrysPerAsset; e++) {
            printf("%d ", bbb[a][e]);
        }
    }
    // bbb does not need free(bbb); because it is released with the function end.
    // and yep, there was no malloc for bbb. so we are done.
}
```

and by the way. welcome to C.

Comment: thanks a lot .but i think in the first part, that your aaa is just a 1-D array pointer.Right ?But, it sitll a good stuff to help me with a comprehension to 2-D array.

Comment: `size_t datalen = entrys * sizeof(p); p = malloc(datalen);` calculates the size incorrectly. It should be `entrys * sizeof *p`.

Comment: `int bbb[maxAssets][entrysPerAsset] = {};` has two problems. Initializer lists may not be empty in the C grammar, per C 2018 6.7.9 1, and the C standard does not define initializing variable length arrays, which this is because `maxAssets` is not a constant as defined by the C standard.